# Irrationality or transcendence of $i^{i\Omega}$ and $2^\Omega$, with $\Omega=W(1)$ and $W(x)$ being the main branch of Lambert $W$ function

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendence

In this post we denote the main (or principal) branch of the Lambert $W$ function as $W(x)$, I add as reference that Wikipedia has the article [*Lambert* $W$ *function.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) The particular value $W(1)=\Omega$ is known as the omega constant, see the Wikipedia [*Omega constant.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant) We denote the imaginary unit as $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to deduce what about the irrationality or transcendence of each one of the following real constants $i^{i\Omega}$ and $2^{\Omega}$. I emphasize that I'm asking **what work can be done** about these, before I'm accepting an answer. **Many thanks.**

I'm asking what about the state of art, or **what work can be done** for my question. I don't know if my question is in the literature, if this is the case please refer the literature answering as a reference request and I try to search and read the statements from the literature. For the first question I tried a variant of Gelfond's constant, and for the second question I wondered about it, if I'm remember well and I'm right, in the context of an application of the six exponentials theorem.

I was inspired in my question posted on Mathematics Stack Exchange [MSE **3579844**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579844/what-about-of-the-irrationality-and-transcendence-of-expressions-involving-the-o) (asked Mar 13) that previously I've also asked on MathOverflow, and in the linked section of the Wikipedia's article with title [*List of unsolved problems in mathematics.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Analysis) As reference I know also the statement of Gelfond–Schneider theorem

Comment: For the persons interested in this kind of questions, there is an excellent preprint on arXiv by Wadim Zudilin as **arXiv:2004.11029** and title *Diophantine problems related to the Omega constant*

Comment: Many thanks for the edit (I had not noticed the typo) @J.W.Tanner